# Which is faster? Contacts access or database Access?

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite

I am working on an android contacts app. I want the contacts to be loaded and searched faster.
I would like to know which method the contacts should be accessed?

Through the phone's contact book with ContactsContract OR by creating own app-specific database with sqlite?

Comment: use ContactsContract, where did you find other solution ?

Comment: @pskink I thought something like to create the database while running the app for the first time, and later use and optimize it accordingly.

Comment: and the std db is not optimized? do you have any performance problems?

Comment: @pskink Well, generally all contacts app take little time to load contacts in each run, I just want to save it by doing some optimizations, like loading only first 30 contacts from the database.

Comment: Unless you are planning on having the user manually resupply you with all of her contacts, your database will be empty. While it is faster to load and search an empty database, the user may be unimpressed with the results.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't expect user to resupply the contacts. I would be creating the database from ContactContract for the first time only. After that I willbe using my own database for optimizations purposes as mentioned in above comments.

Comment: @SanjayVerma and how many contacts do. you have? 1000, 10000, more?

Comment: Your copy of the contacts will rapidly become out of sync with what the user thinks her "real" contacts are.

Comment: @pskink For a normal user, I am expecting around 500+ contacts.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, that's a problem, but will be taken care of using periodic contacts count check, direct-to-root insertion, occasional syncing etc. I will be using a separate thread for such background tasks.

Comment: @SanjayVerma ok so check this gist i cteated today for another SO question: https://gist.github.com/pskink/5fe9c0bb4677c1debc5e and see if its fast enough or not

Comment: So, you are going to do all this work, and add all sorts of privacy/security issues as well due to the data duplication, rather than simply find a way to use `ContactsContract` better?

Comment: @CommonsWare +1 for the privacy/security point. I am exploring all the options. And for search operation, I am thinking of using suffix tree. And for all that I need to know the performance impact I that will incur due to database access.

Comment: @SanjayVerma is the ContactContract's performance not good enough? did you try my gist?

Comment: @pskink It would be great if you could give a brief idea of what exactly you gist does.

Comment: @SanjayVerma looks up for specific contact or email